# Repeating sets of rows according to the number of rows by column in R with data.table

Tags: r, data.table

Currently in R, I am trying to do the following for data.table table:

Suppose my data looks like:

```
Class   Person ID      Index
A       1              3
A       2              3
A       5              3
B       7              2
B       12             2
C       18             1
D       25             2
D       44             2
```

Here, the class refers to the class a person belongs to. The Person ID variable represents a unique identifier of a person. Finally, the **Index** tells us how many people are in each class.

From this, I would like to create a new data table as so:

```
Class   Person ID      Index
A       1              3
A       2              3
A       5              3
A       1              3
A       2              3
A       5              3
A       1              3
A       2              3
A       5              3
B       7              2
B       12             2
B       7              2
B       12             2
C       18             1
D       25             2
D       44             2
D       25             2
D       44             2
```

where we repeated each set of persons by class based on the index variable. Hence, we would repeat the class A by 3 times because the index says 3.

So far, my code looks like:

```
setDT(data)[, list(Class = rep(Person ID, seq_len(.N)), Person ID = sequence(seq_len(.N)), by = Index]
```

However, I am not getting the correct result and I feel like there is a simpler way to do this. Would anyone have any ideas? Thank you!

Comment: Does it need to be in the order you've shown? If not, this should do: `setDT(df)[rep(1:nrow(df), df$Index)]`.

Answer (score 2):

If that particular order is important to you, then perhaps something like this should work:

```
setDT(data)[, list(PersonID, sequence(rep(.N, Index))), by = list(Class, Index)]
#     Class Index PersonID V2
#  1:     A     3        1  1
#  2:     A     3        2  2
#  3:     A     3        5  3
#  4:     A     3        1  1
#  5:     A     3        2  2
#  6:     A     3        5  3
#  7:     A     3        1  1
#  8:     A     3        2  2
#  9:     A     3        5  3
# 10:     B     2        7  1
# 11:     B     2       12  2
# 12:     B     2        7  1
# 13:     B     2       12  2
# 14:     C     1       18  1
# 15:     D     2       25  1
# 16:     D     2       44  2
# 17:     D     2       25  1
# 18:     D     2       44  2
```

If the order is not important, perhaps:

```
setDT(data)[rep(1:nrow(data), Index)]
```

Answer (score 0):

Here is a way using `dplyr` in case you wanted to try

```
library(dplyr)
data %>%
group_by(Class) %>% 
do(data.frame(.[sequence(.$Index[row(.)[,1]]),]))
```

which gives the output

```
 #      Class Person.ID Index
 #1      A         1     3
 #2      A         2     3
 #3      A         5     3
 #4      A         1     3
 #5      A         2     3
 #6      A         5     3
 #7      A         1     3
 #8      A         2     3
 #9      A         5     3
 #10     B         7     2
 #11     B        12     2
 #12     B         7     2
 #13     B        12     2
 #14     C        18     1
 #15     D        25     2
 #16     D        44     2
 #17     D        25     2
 #18     D        44     2
```